# Installing Quickstart UI for IdentityServer4

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, identityserver4

I created an empty asp.net core web application (`dotnet new web -n <projectname>`) and went [to the github for IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI) and was followed the instructions to add the quickstart UI. I first did the powershell cmd `iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI/main/getmain.ps1'))` to download the files and run the application but it keeps telling me `Index not found` but the file is inside of the `Views` folder. So I then deleted all those files it downloaded from the project and installed it using its templates by running the cmds `dotnet new -i identityserver4.templates` then `dotnet new is4ui --force` which downloaded those files again onto my project. However, it keeps telling me the same message.

**I noticed that under the `Quickstart` folder, contains a folder named `Home` which has the `HomeController.cs` and the namespace is as `IdentityServerHost.Quickstart.UI`... do I need to change that namespace to match my solution i.e. `ids.Quickstart.Home`?**

**What is causing this to display that error when infact there is the Index.cshtml file inside of the Views folder?****

[image]

This is my `startup.cs` file:

```
namespace ids
{
    public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddInMemoryClients(Config.Clients)
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.IdentityResources)
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.ApiResources)
                .AddInMemoryApiScopes(Config.ApiScopes)
                .AddTestUsers(Config.Users)
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential();

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            //  app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute());

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

        }
    }
}
```

Here is the `Index.cshtml`

[image]

Comment: Make sure your Views are stored in folder structure like `~/Views/{ControllerName}/{ViewName}`

Comment: As in have a controller named `HomeController`?

Comment: Right. A view needs a corresponding controller to handle its requests- if I understand the whole thing properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your `app.UseEndpoints( endpoints => ...)` line, in your `Configure()` method to the following:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Then, make sure you have a `HomeController`. Create a folder in your project named `Controllers`. The path should be `~/Controllers/{ControllerName}.cs` while your views should be `~/Views/Home/{ViewName}.cshtml`. In this case, Your `{ViewName}.cshtml` will be `Index.cshtml` and your controller name will be `HomeController.cs`.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    // Default return when user performs GET HTTP request
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure why I still am getting the same error message from the original post even after doing as you said. I made sure that `Index.cshtml` file is how you said it to be along with the controller named `Home` but it still display that as soon as the program starts

Comment: This may be a helpful article as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: Following this Tutorial is also how I learned how to set up my first ASP.NET Core project: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: @NoviceCoder, Also double check spelling of your `folders`, `methods`, `calls`, etc. Else it may be trying to look somewhere that doesn't actually exist. I ran into that a couple times.

Comment: Thank you for the articles and help! I will look into this and double check the spelling of each item as well, thanks again!

Comment: Please take a look at my updated post so you can see what exactly I am trying to do... maybe you are able to see the issue...

Answer (score 1):

Right click on `Index.cshtml`, choose the property option. Check setting in the
properties windows. The build action of `Index.cshtml` must be **Content**.

[image]

Comment: I just checked to see if it as shown in your screenshot, and it is exactly as yours still returns the message :(

Comment: Please take a look at my updated post so you can see what exactly I am trying to do... maybe you are able to see the issue